No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. a pesar de tener los headers correspondientes
Estoy intentando desde mi frontend de angular acceder a mi api de php, pero recibo el siguiente mensaje: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/freelancer/backend/usuarios' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
El problema es que mi archivo api.php si tiene los headers para permitir CORS
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); // Permitir todas las orígenes
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS"); // Métodos permitidos
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization"); // Encabezados permitidos

// Si la solicitud es OPTIONS, simplemente retorna un 200
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    http_response_code(200);
    exit;
}
require_once(__DIR__.'/../config/generals.php');
function postRestablecer () {
    $db = conectarBD();
    $tables = array(
        'trabajadores_resenas',
        'empleadores_resenas',
        'resenas',
        'trabajadores_habilidades',
        'empleadores_habilidades',
        'trabajadores',
        'empleadores',
        'habilidadess',
        'usuarios'
    );
    
    foreach ($tables as $table) {
        $sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $table";
        if ($db->query($sql) === FALSE) {
            echo "Error al eliminar la tabla $table: " . $db->error . "<br>";
        }
    }
    
    // Crear las tablas nuevamente
    $sql = file_get_contents('../storage/dump.sql');
    if ($db->multi_query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Tablas creadas correctamente<br>";
    } else {
        echo "Error al crear las tablas: " . $db->error . "<br>";
    }
    
    mysqli_close($db);
    outputJson([], 201);
}


// Funciones para el administrador
function getUsuarios() 
{
    $db = conectarBD();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    if ($result===false) {
        print mysqli_error($db);
        outputError(500);
    }
    $ret = [];
    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        settype($fila['id_user'], 'integer');
        $ret[] = $fila;
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_close($db);
    outputJson($ret);
}

